# Get value from input field and pass to new page using ajax without submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form which has an **email** field:

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email"/>
```

And a **verify** button:

```
<span style="cursor:pointer">
 <p id="verify">Verify</p>
</span>
```

When user clicks on this **verify**, an input field(in verify_ajax.php) is loaded using following script which ask for verification code,

```
<script>
 $function()
 {
    $('#verify').click(function(){

    $('#getcode').load('verify_ajax') 

    }
 }
</script>
```

Here, **getcode** is where the ajax content will be loaded.
Now, i want to pass **email** to the page **verify_ajax** (loaded in above function). I am new to all this ajax, please help me with this code.

**UPDATE:** I passed using ajax like:

```
<script>
 $function()
 {
    $('#verify').click(function(){

    $('#getcode').load('verify_ajax?email='+$('#email').val()) 

    })
 })
</script>
```

And, there is no error, verification code input is loading.
But there is no email on verify_ajax, I think i am doing some mistake on that page: **verify_ajax.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['email'])
    echo 'Working'.$_GET['email']
```

This is showing only **Working** as output.

Answer (score 0):

use form serialization and then send it to the page.

```
var data = $('#FormId').serializeArray();
$('#getcode').load('verify_ajax',data);
```